# Android KeyStore : Failed to generate self-signed certificate , invalid date string

Tags: java, android, x509certificate

I 'm trying to create keyPair using android Keystore following my code :

```
Calendar start = Calendar.getInstance();
                Calendar end = Calendar.getInstance();
                end.add(Calendar.YEAR, 10);
                KeyPairGeneratorSpec spec = new KeyPairGeneratorSpec.Builder(MyApplication.getInstance())
                        .setAlias(m_alias)
                        .setSubject(new X500Principal("CN="+m_alias))
                        .setSerialNumber(BigInteger.ONE)
                        .setStartDate(start.getTime())
                        .setEndDate(end.getTime())
                        .build();
                KeyPairGenerator generator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA", "AndroidKeyStore");
                generator.initialize(spec);

                KeyPair keyPair = generator.generateKeyPair();
```

At runtime I got this exception :

```
java.security.ProviderException: Failed to generate self-signed certificate
             at android.security.keystore.AndroidKeyStoreKeyPairGeneratorSpi.generateKeyPair(AndroidKeyStoreKeyPairGeneratorSpi.java:504)
             at java.security.KeyPairGenerator$KeyPairGeneratorImpl.generateKeyPair(KeyPairGenerator.java:276)

....
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: invalid date string: Unparseable date: "af`cab`hdedfGMT+00:00" (at offset 0)
             at com.android.org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1UTCTime.<init>(ASN1UTCTime.java:115)
             at com.android.org.bouncycastle.asn1.DERUTCTime.<init>(DERUTCTime.java:23)
             at com.android.org.bouncycastle.asn1.x509.Time.<init>(Time.java:67)
```

I searched about this issue and didn't find any possible solution, Please your help to fix the issue.

**Notes :**
- Device : HTC M9 , Android v.6.0, build number : 3.35.401.12

- Date format examples : start Date : Sat Mar 12 23:10:08 GMT+03:00 2016 . End Date : Thu Mar 12 23:10:08 GMT+03:00 2026

Thanks in advance.

Comment: 1. What's the device model, Android version, build number of the Android device on which this is occurring? 2. What's printed if you print out the start and end variables just before generateKeyPair?

Comment: Device : HTC M9 , Android v.6.0, build number : 3.35.401.12

Comment: Date format examples : start Date : Sat Mar 12 23:10:08 GMT+03:00 2016 .             End Date : Thu Mar 12 23:10:08 GMT+03:00 2026

Comment: Thanks. I found similar issues reported on Android in BouncyCastle/SpongyCastle self-signed certificate generation code (https://gitlab.com/fdroid/fdroidclient/issues/334). To confirm, (1) what language/locale is selected as your system language in System settings -> Language & Input, (2) what does start.getTime() and end.getTime() print out?, (3) does the issue go away if you switch the system language to English (US)?

Comment: @Alex thanks for your help, My locale is English (US). I mentioned in the last comment the printed format for both start and end dates.

Comment: @Radi This doesn't look like it should be compiling, considering [`KeyPairGeneratorSpec.Builder`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/security/KeyPairGeneratorSpec.Builder.html) `getStartDate` does not take a long value (what `date.getTime` returns), it takes a `Date`.

Comment: @Bryan I am using calendar.getTime() which returns Date object, https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#getTime()

Comment: @Radi Ah, my mistake. This is a strange issue, it looks like the date you are supplying is getting jumbled somehow. The date that it is trying to parse; "af`cab`hdedfGMT+00:00" seems like gibberish.

Comment: @Radi Did you find any solution?

Answer (score 1):

Key store issue with Arabic or Persian

When keystore generates the key pair, it generates a self signed cert. The ASN1 parser used internally by Android Keystore doesn't correctly take in the locale and it causes the failures for device locale with language from right to left. Sample stack trace:

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: invalid date string: Unparseable date: "÷ððñðñððððððGMT+00:00" 
    at com.android.org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1UTCTime.(ASN1UTCTime.java:115)
    at com.android.org.bouncycastle.asn1.DERUTCTime.(DERUTCTime.java:23)
    at com.android.org.bouncycastle.asn1.x509.Time.(Time.java:67)
    at android.security.keystore.AndroidKeyStoreKeyPairGeneratorSpi.generateSelfSignedCertificateWithFakeSignature(AndroidKeyStoreKeyPairGeneratorSpi.java:696)

Issues reported to google: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=207613

Answer (score 1):

As @Muralidhar says, it is a [known issue with AndroidKeyStore](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37095309).

Android KeyStore doesn't correctly take in the locale and it causes the failures for device locale with language from right to left.

A workaround is setting English locale before generating a key pair and changing it back after all. Take a look to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46602170/6305235).