# Error running 'app': No target device found

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

> ٠٧:٤٨ ص   Plugin Error: Plugin "Android WiFi ADB" is incompatible (supported only in IntelliJ IDEA).
>
> ٠٧:٤٨ ص   * daemon not running; starting now at tcp:5037
>
> ٠٧:٤٨ ص   * daemon started successfully
>
> ٠٧:٥٠ ص   Error running 'app': No target device found.
>
> ٠٧:٥٠ ص   Error running 'app': No target device found.
>
> ٠٧:٥٧ ص   Executing tasks: [:app:assembleDebug] in project C:> \Users\Mmsk4\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApplication
>
> ٠٧:٥٧ ص   Gradle build failed in 28 s 633 ms

[image]

Comment: Your problem is not "*Error running 'app': No target device found.*" but the build error shown on the left: "*invalid date string: unparseable date [...]*"

Comment: How to solve it ?

Comment: Have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35987510/illegalargumentexception-unparseable-date-during-androidkeystore-key-generatio/46602170#46602170

Comment: Im dont undrrstand this .

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for plugin. You can achieve the same without plugin. The setup is one time.
[Android | WiFi adb keeps disconnecting in android studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67318581/android-wifi-adb-keeps-disconnecting-in-android-studio)

Go, through this post. It has full guide to run app through wifi adb.